# How can i store previous page url as string in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, url

[How can i store prev page url as string?It does not works..please help][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ylxn.png

Comment: Are you sure it is `route component`. Is your component the one that is passed in to the VueRouter? Because that function only triggers in those components.

Comment: Welcome! Please post your code as test (in code format), not as image!